# Fastest way to update attribute in in list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have 2 lists of dictionary and I get an update message with new attributes for a specific order in any of the 2 lists. (and I cannot merge the lists)

So let's say I have the following:

```
orders_list1=[
    {"price":1, "quantity":20, "orderID":"order1"},
    {"price":2, "quantity":10, "orderID":"order2"}]

orders_list2=[
    {"price":1, "quantity":20, "orderID":"order3"},
    {"price":2, "quantity":10, "orderID":"order4"}]

message = {"action": "update", "data": [{"orderID":"order2", "price":5}]}
```

Then I'd like to obtain:

```
orders_list1=[
    {"price":1, "quantity":20, "orderID":"order1"},
    {"price":5, "quantity":10, "orderID":"order2"}]

orders_list2=[
    {"price":1, "quantity":20, "orderID":"order3"},
    {"price":2, "quantity":10, "orderID":"order4"}]
```

I would like to update in a fast way the appropriate order. I don't think for loops are the fastest.

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Nicolas, can you clarify what you mean by attribute, here? Do you mean like price, quantity, orderID? Also, is that message supposed to specify what the update should be (i.e. you want to update the price for orderID 2)?

Comment: The message just say update but it is always the price. And attribute I meant then just update the price of the appropriate orderID

Comment: So the lists here have lengths of only 2. How long, potentially, will the lists be? If you order them by `orderID` (which is how they're ordered in your example), you could avoid having to iterate over _every_ item in the lists to find the right one.

Comment: the lists can be up to 200 lengths each. And i've updated the code snippet. OrderIDs are strings indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding:

1. `orders_list1` and `orders_list2` are list of dictionaries, where, each dictionary has a unique `orderID`
2. In my opinion, it would have been more efficient if you had nested dictionaries as follows:

```
orders_dict1={ 
    "order1" : {"price":1, "quantity":20, "orderID":"order1"},
    "order2" : {"price":2, "quantity":10, "orderID":"order2"}
    }

orders_dict2={
    "order3" : {"price":1, "quantity":20, "orderID":"order3"},
    "order4" : {"price":2, "quantity":10, "orderID":"order4"}
    }
# Then all you had to do would be
for update_item in message['data']:
    oid = update_item['orderID']

    if oid in order_dict1:
        orders_dict1[oid]['price'] = update_item['price']
    elif oid in order_dict2:
        orders_dict2[oid]['price'] = update_item['price']
    else:
        # handle error case
```

Assuming, above suggestion is not possible, fastest way would be list comprehension

```
for update_item in message['data']:
    oid = update_item['orderID']

    idx = [i for i, dt in enumerate(orders_list1) if dt['orderID']==oid]
    orders_list1[idx[0]]['price']=update_item['price']

    if len(idx) == 0:
        idx = [i for i, dt in enumerate(orders_list2) if dt['orderID']==oid]
        orders_list2[idx[0]]['price']=update_item['price']
```